# How to find position of missing values in a vector

Tags: r, na, missing-data

What features does the R language have to find missing values in dataframe or at least, how to know that the dataframe has missing values?

Comment: all the ones under `?NA`

Comment: `data[is.na(data),]`

Comment: I correctly assume that `anyNA(x)` will return TRUE **only** if x is contained a missing value?

Comment: what wrong with `data[is.na(data),]`?

Comment: @validoll - try it, it gives nonsense results: `dat <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,3),b=c(NA,2,3)); dat[is.na(dat),]`

Comment: @validoll `is.na(data)` will give you a row-by-column sized matrix of trues and falses... which is a bad (nonsensical) thing to pass to the row argument of `[`.

Comment: And, @validoll you don't have to assume, you can also read the documentation: "The generic function `anyNA` implements `any(is.na(x))`"

Comment: Why don't you use summary(data)? Then you will see which columns contain NA values and how many.

Comment: @MichaelVE - because `summary(data)` gives a lot of otherwise unnecessary information and can't be used for subsetting or replacement of NA values. Using `is.na` in combination with `lapply` or `which` or similar would be preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = matrix(rep(c(NA, 1,NA), 3), ncol=3, nrow=3)
print(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

matrix of boolean values: is the value NA

```
is.na(x)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

indices of NA values:

```
which(is.na(x), arr.ind = T)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   3   1
[3,]   1   2
[4,]   3   2
[5,]   1   3
[6,]   3   3
```

see if the matrix has any missing values:

```
any(is.na(x))
TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell based on the example you've given, more details on the structure of "data" would be helpful, but, if you simply want to exclude any observation (row) of your data that has a missing value anywhere in it, try:

```
cleanDat <- na.omit(data)
```

Note, there is a nice [tutorial on missing data](http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html]) which is where I looked to confirm I had this right.